# Grid control that can be placed on userform?

Tags: excel, adodb, gridcontrol, vba

Does anyone know of a grid control that can be placed on an Excel UserForm, preferably something that is capable of displaying the content of a ADODB Recordset?

Comment: (1) This might be of interest: http://10tec.com/activex-grid/.  (2) I have not tried it for years by I recall displaying multi-column ListBoxes.  If this sounds interesting, I will check some old code to see if my memory is correct.

Comment: You can use Microsoft Web Browser additional control on userform for displaying converted to table ADODB Recordset content.

Answer (score 3):

In VB window using 'Tools'->'Additional Controls' menu, there may be DBGrid control; check it.

Answer (score 2):

In the VB window, using 'Tools->Additional Controls, there is a 'Microsoft Office Spreadsheet 11.0' control that is very powerful. This is true for Excel 2010, at least. Don't know about more recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there for anyone that might be interested. I too as looking for a way to display what looks like a grid on a userform. Since I'm working on a shared program with different users having different versions, I shied away from the "Additional Controls.
Very simply, what I did was throw a number of labels into a frame, got rid of the borders, separated them with just the tiniest space in between and set the back color of the frame to a darker color. The result is below.
[image: img]